# How to display loading icon when autocomplete search is performed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to display that in the separate div (so `.ui-autocomplete-loading` is not applicable here). I can start to show that when `search` event is happened. But how can I understand when it should be hidden?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a remote data source. If so, use `$.ajax` inside of a function you supply to the `source` parameter. For example:

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $("#loading").show(); // Where #loading is the loading indicator

        $.ajax({
            url: "Your_URL_HERE",
            data: request.term,
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
                $("#loading").hide();
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#loading").hide();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gKFJU/

Comment: I tried this and found the loading element sometimes get hidden before the menu is updated.  I tried hiding it on the ajax `complete` event but no improvement.  The only thing I've done that works is hide it on both `open` and `close` autocomplete events.  Any idea why this would be the case?  The behavior seems to indicate there is sometimes a delay for the menu to update *after* the ajax completes.

Comment: @billynoah this is because of race condition. For example: user types "foo" which fires an XHR with term = "foo", then types "bar" which fires another XHR with term = "foobar". Suppose the "foo" request completes first; which means you hide the loading icon. But the menu will not display because autocomplete waits for the "foobar" request to complete in order to show the menu. Note that the plugin handles race conditions behind the scenes and intelligently handles out-of-order AJAX requests.

Comment: ok thanks.  i guess in that case using `open` and `close` events is a better at removing the loading element only when the plugin has completed all current requests.  Do you agree?  Can you think of any better way to handle this?

Comment: @billynoah: Salman is right, this answer isn't really deep enough to handle race conditions with AJAX requests. What I'd do is look at the default implementation for the `source` function in the autocomplete widget and emulate that. Using `open` and `close` sounds like a good idea too.

Answer (score 4):

**CSS Solution**

If the loading element is a sibling of the input control then CSS general sibling selector can be used:

```css
.loading {
    /* whatever */
}
#autocomplete.ui-autocomplete-loading ~ .loading {
    background-image: url(loading.gif);
}
```

[**Working example**](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2013/12/jquery-ui-autocomplete-examples.html#example-5)

**jQuery Solution**

You can add the [`search`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search) and [`response`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) event handlers.

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 3,
    source: "/search.json",
    search: function () {
        $("#loading2").show();
    },
    response: function () {
        $("#loading2").hide();
    }
});
```

Note that this approach suffers from race conditions since (i) AJAX requests do not necessarily finish in the order they were started (ii) autocomplete may fire fewer response events than search.

[**Combined demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Ad95A/)