# jqGrid inline editing autocomplete preloader icon

Tags: jqgrid, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete field working fine on inline editing, but i would like to have the nice-ajax-preloader-icon that its shown at the right side of the field while the data is being requested/loaded, like on this non inline example: http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/integrations/autocomplete/default.php (right on the ShipName field)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should answer your question:

[How to display loading icon when autocomplete search is performed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959373/how-to-display-loading-icon-when-autocomplete-search-is-performed)

Basically it's just turning on the loading icon and then turning it off when you get the response.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you :), i was looking for the simplest way to do it, and your answer lead me to that. It was that my jquery-ui CSS file was a bit outdated and didn't have the class 'ui-autocomplete-loading', which is pointed in the link you passed, i had to add the class only in the CSS file and get the preloader icon, fixed a couple of issues about the input field border, and now its working just as i wanted.

Comment: The demo page http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/integrations/autocomplete/default.php uses jQuery UI 1.8.2 which was the last version of jQuery UI which defines CSS style `.ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url('images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') right center no-repeat; }`. More recent versions of jQuery UI still use `.addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading")` on `search` and do `.removeClass("ui-autocomplete-loading")` on `response`. So **martindhx** you are right, one need really just define *manually* CSS rule with class `ui-autocomplete-loading` and animated image.

Comment: @martindhx: you can for example copy http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/redmond/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif in your site or just use the URL directly. So including the following CSS style `.ui-autocomplete-loading { background: white url("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/redmond/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat; }` should solve your problem

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you very much man, not only for this one (i will surely make the proper changes to be fine with the latest version) but for dozens and dozens of issues that your great answers helped me resolve in my jqGrid project incursion. I hope you really have the dimension of how valuable is your help, surely lot of people 'in the dark', as i was, is getting a great deal of support from your posts. So keep it up man :D

Comment: @martindhx: Many thanks for good words about my old answers on the stackoveflow. I'm glad that I could help you. You are welcome!